# Nodejs- combine two diffrent lists into one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got two models in mongoose:

```
const user = mongoose.Schema({ 
    name: String,
    ...
});
```

and

```
const moderator = mongoose.Schema({ 
    name: String,
    ...
});
```

When I access these collections with:

```
user.find()
```

I get in response list of users and moderators separetly.

What I want to achive is to join these two list together to get a list based on this model:

```
const myDataSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 

user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'},
moderator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'moderator'}

});
```

Where one of attributes (either user or moderator) will be set.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Instead of using the mongoose schema I created my "own object". My code:

```
                    let list= [];

                     users.forEach( function (user)
                    {
                        list.push({user: user});
                    });

                    moderators.forEach( function (moderator)
                    {
                        list.push({moderator: moderator});
                    });
```

It's probaly not the most efficient way but it works.